# jQuery retrieve elements from nested classes

Tags: jquery

I have this portion of html:

```
<div class="ThirdRowBanner">
    <div class="yCmsComponent col-xs-12">
        <div class="simple-banner-component simple-banner">
            <img title="sometitle" alt="somealt" src="someurl/apparel-category-banner.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I retrieve with jQuery img title, alt and src elements?
I can't add ids or other tag to the img. I can only start from the "ThirdRowBanner" class.

Comment: have you tried `$('.ThirdRowBanner').find('img')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.find` from that class:

```
$("div.ThirdRowBanner").find("img").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("title")); 
    console.log($(this).attr("src")); 
    console.log($(this).attr("alt")); 
});
```